# Unicode bug symbol that can display inside browsers

Tags: browser, unicode, character-encoding, github, ascii

I'm trying to replace my `bug` label in my GitHub project's **Issues** tracker, for a symbol of an actual bug. I found [this nasty looking creature](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f41b/index.htm) and [this lady bug](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f41e/index.htm) but it seems they are too far "out of range" to be displayable in a browser. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The characters mentioned are not “out of range”; even though they are Plane 1 characters, and you might have difficulties in typing them on your keyboard, they work just fine in browsers (when entered as such or as character references), *provided that* they can be found in the font being used. The possibility of using all kinds of special characters in web pages is really a font issue more than anything else.

And in terms of characters supported by at least commonly installed font, there is nothing that even remotely resembles a bug. So if you wanted to use a character instead of an image (a goal that might be pointless), a downloadable font (web font, with `@font-face`) is the only feasible option.

This means that you should look at the glyphs of some pictograms *in different fonts* where they are available, rather than at just the representative glyphs in the Unicode Standard. My idea of a (software) bug more or less matches ANT (U+1F41C) in the Segoe UI Symbol font. Unfortunately, there seems to be about one free font that contains ANT, Symbola, and in it it’s not that “buggy”, but maybe reasonably well. So what I would do *if* I insisted on using a bug *character* is

```
<style>
@font-face { font-family: Symbola;
  /* here the usual stuff for Symbola, the usual bulletproof syntax */
}
.bug { font-family: Segoe UI Symbol, Symbola; }
</style>
<span style=bug>&#x1f41c;</span>
```

But I’m afraid it would be overkill to have Symbola (a fairly large font) as a downloadable font for just the sake of a character that isn’t that much of a *text* character. And ANT “” might not look very readable in common text sizes.